# How to set user and password for Soap Message to call services from wsdl link?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a wsdl. The url: `localhost:8181/McaBusiness/services/MCAPort?wsdl`
I use SOAPMessage to call services from there.

In request sending i've set

```
    SOAPElement security =
            header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

    SOAPElement usernameToken =
            security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");
    usernameToken.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");

    SOAPElement username =
            usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");
    username.addTextNode("user");

    SOAPElement password =
            usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");
    password.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
    password.addTextNode("pass");
```

But when call service it has error about authenticate.
Can you help me about that?

Comment: Can you share error message?

Comment: Hi @herry message content is 
SOAPException: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized java

Comment: I suppose readers of this question will be interested for [this](https://gist.github.com/sivaprasadreddy/2555700) solution that appears to be for exactly the same problem of exactly the same user.